# How to consume C# webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services

I practice some web service to know more about the limit of input and output they can receive. Is any parameter can use (include instance data type) in webservice? If true how can I consume this webservice?

```
[WebMethod]
public string uploadFile(string path, string fileName, string mimeType, byte[] documentContent){
    return ECMApi.createDocumentByPath(path, fileName, mimeType, documentContent);
}
```

Comment: Your question is kind of broad so you may want to narrow it down to more specifically what you are wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If by instance type you are referring to a reference object as opposed to value type, then yes you can you them. There may be different constraints if you are using REST, or WCF, or calling web methods via ajax.